# Adding Emacs SES Mode Grid Lines

Tags: hooks, spreadsheet

Began here using Emacs `SES` mode for some spreadsheets, but seems by default to lack the grid lines to help locating the cells and its values.

Looks like it should be in some sort of hook in my `.emacs` file, but until now I don't know how to enable it.

Any idea?